# Why this IFrame is not taking complete page height?

Tags: html, css, iframe, height

I am using Iframe to display google.com [ or say any website ]. I have used height=100% but even then my Iframe size is just half the page. Please let me know why it is happening.
Here is the link:

http://jsbin.com/anola3

Comment: Google refuses to run in `iframe` as of now (speaking of "not being evil"). Bing is ok with it (but of course they may decide otherwise any time in the future).

Comment: You need to use CSS to style the iframe (from outside), not deprecated HTML attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `style="position:absolute;"` on the iframe